# How to get bounding box of a wms layer in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

I want to fit the map on a specific wms layer in leaflet. for this, I try to get bounding box of the wms layer and then use the map.fitBounds(bbox) method. but I don't know how to get the bounding box of a layer! can somebody give me a solution? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your WMS server, the `capabilities` of your WMS layers might contain bounding box information.

Perform a `GetCapabilities` request (see e.g. https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WMS+-+GetCapabilities ), parse that document (see e.g. https://github.com/w8r/wms-capabilities ), and locate the appropiate WMS layer(s). Bounding box information should be there.

Please note that Leaflet does not request the `capabilities` of the WMS server, and does not have built-in facilities for parsing it.